# Что нужно учить для Бека сайтов?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, frontend, backend

Итак, если не сложно, то мне нужен список того что нужно учить для бекенда (пометочка, я уже изучаю python), в направлении веб разработки. Что вообще нужно знать чтобы сделать хотя-бы одностраничник. И если вы будете милосердны, замолвите словечко о фронте. Спасибо, благодаря вам в мире состоялся программист.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+roadmap+backend

Comment: https://roadmap.sh/

Comment: _Что вообще нужно знать чтобы сделать хотя-бы одностраничник._ html, css